# Adding onclick attribute to menu links

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm trying to add the onclick attribute to some menu links in Drupal 8 in order to track conversions with Google.

Here's a tutorial for [adding onclick events in Drupal 7](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/onclick/) that uses the [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

For Drupal 8, I looked at the [Link attributes module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes) and the [Menu Link attributes module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) but these only allow you to add classes, not set the value for onclick.

Comment: Can't you add the onclick event in a js file?

Comment: Attaching an event solely with JS is much cleaner, and won't require any extra modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) is the way to go now. It makes menu items fieldable. And you probably also get the proper template suggestions already.

> Menu Item Extras provides extra fields for the Menu Items without
>   using additional entities. This module is NOT an alternative of all
>   Mega Menu modules - it is unique implementation of Drupal core’s Menu
>   system. All fields are placed upon the Menu Item edit/add form and use
>   core Menu link content entity for storing all data.